# How do you select the text within <pre> using Xpath?

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm trying to get the text within pre tags in C# which uses Xpath. The webpage only consists of the following:

```
<body>
    <pre>
        The text I am trying to select
    </pre>
</body>
```

I can't seem to select just that text and I don't exactly know how to put that in a string. This is the code I'm using:

```
var WebgetME2_ = new HtmlWeb();
var docME2_ = WebgetME2_.Load(webpage); //loading the webpage
HtmlNode NODEME2_ = docME2_.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*/pre"); //select the node
string innerME_ = NODEME2_.InnerText; //put the node innertext in string
// After getting the text within the <pre> tags I want to select a part of it using RegEx, that's why I need it in a string
string imagineME2_ = Regex.Match(innerME_, "(?=http)(.+?)(?<=.jpg)").ToString();
```

Comment: open the file in chrome and in its developer console inspect the thin you want. right click on the item will give you the option to  copy its xpath to the clipboard. better then guessing

Comment: @user853710 I'm using FireFox and it gives me the CSS selector which is `body > pre` but C# uses Xpath. I have tried `body/pre` too which is the Xpath equivalent of the CSS selector but that didn't work either.

Comment: ty giving it a / at the end

Comment: @user853710 Still nope. I found out that InnerHtml equals the text I want to select so I tried `string INNERE = docME2_.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.ToString();`. Didn't work either.

Comment: In `...SelectSingleNode("//*/pre")` you don't need the `*/`. Just use `...SelectSingleNode("//pre")` and use the `.InnerText` method to access the contents of the first matching node if not `null`.

Comment: @zx485 Alright did that, made an if to check if the node is not null, but the code skips it which means the node is null. I don't get that because the node on the webpage isn't null, it always has that line of text. I've tried so many things and already spent a few hours yesterday and today to figure this out but I just don't get it...

Comment: I just did a quick test of the XPath expression with XSLT and it yields the correct result. However, considering your RegEx expression, the result string will be totally wrong. The expression `string imagineME2_ = Regex.Match(...)` will return String.Empty on your sample HTML data. The RegEx is messed up.

Comment: It could be a default namespace preventing your xpath from working. Try `//*[local-name()='pre']` and see if that selects the node.

Comment: @DanielHaley Got a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to bypass the problem.

```
System.Net.WebClient WebclientME_ = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] rawME_ = WebclientME_.DownloadData(webpage); //download page
string innerME_ = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawME_); //write to a string
string imagineME2_ = Regex.Match(innerME_, "(?=http)(.+?)(?<=.jpg)").ToString();
```

It downloads the page which I'm not fond of because it works slower but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below Xpath :-

```
/body/pre/text()
```

`text()` function will retrieve all text for you from the path you have mentioned in the Xpath

pre should be the child of body.. If it is not your real structure then use double slash `//` .... `//` means it will find the pre node from your complete DOM.

You can also give a try with below Xpath:-

```
/body//pre/text()
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Still getting a NullReferenceException. Tried both and also tried `webget.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//pre").FirstChild.ToString();` & `webget.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body/pre").InnerText`. Tried all possible variations...